# Deploying multiple builds of a nodejs app on one server

Tags: node.js, server, serverless-framework

We have about 200 customers and for each one, we want to create a separate frontend application. All the frontend apps use the same source code but they get different data from the backend server at build time. So when I change something in the git repository I want all the frontends to rebuild.
Can I handle this on one server? Or are there any other services like serverless services to manage multiple applications?

Answer (score 1):

> So when I change something in the git repository I want all the frontends to rebuild.

Yes, This is called [CI/CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CI/CD)

> Can I handle this on one server?

Yes, You might want to use **Containerization** to deploy similar to multiple "*virtual server*" in a single server. One of the containerization is [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)

> are there any other services like serverless services to manage multiple applications?

After you understand **Docker**(or **Containerization**), you might want to "*orchestrate*" multiple containers, then you can use a tool such as [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/).

if you want serverless, [this](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3510472/5-ways-to-do-serverless-on-kubernetes.html) article might help you.
CMIIW.